# ruby Currency converter Array

Tags: ruby

how the structure has to be to work? need help 
here is the problem and the solution I am working on

Currency converter Array.

Create a method
Create an array called dollars. Fill the Array with 5 currency values.
Create an empty array called euros.
Create code to convert the 5 Dollar currency values into Euros and place the values into the array called euros.

Output euros Array.

```
def convert
dollars = [1,2,3,4,5]

euro = array.new

    if dollars > 0 

        euros = 0.87

        puts  dollars * euros
end
```

Comment: You're looking for `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Use ruby [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map#map-method)

```
dollars = [1,2,3,4,5]

euro = dollars.map {|dollar| dollar * 0.87 }
#=> [0.87, 1.74, 2.61, 3.48, 4.35]
```

Answer (score 0):

following the tip from @tadman, you could do something like this:

```
def converter(array, exchange_rate)
  array.map { |e| e * exchange_rate }
end

converter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0.86) #=> [0.86, 1.72, 2.58, 3.44, 4.3]
```